# Automate clickonce publish with msbuild for project with a project reference

Tags: .net, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am trying to automate a tfs build for a click once .net c# application.
I have edited the default xaml according to the following post: http://blog.dontpaniclabs.com/post/2011/04/29/ClickOnce-Publish-and-Deploy-from-Team-Foundation-Server-2010.aspx
It works well for simple projects that do not have a referenced project, however for a click once project that references a library project it does not work correctly. 
The build succeeds however in reality I am getting the following 2 warnings:

1. Unable to apply publish properties for item "library.dll".
2. Two or more assemblies have the same identity 'clickonceprojectname.Client, Version=1.0.1.17, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4F6F13E2414E9925, ProcessorArchitecture=msil'.

and the library.dll is not included in the application files folder and therefor the click once installation fails.
To me it looks like for some reason the msbuild is trying to publish the dependent project as well as the click once project. Is there any way I can fix this?

I have read many posts and already tried many solutions including making sure that the copy local = true in the project file, and reset all the application files in the publish tab in project properties.
can someone help me with that ? I'm struggling with this for several days

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, we discovered that the cause to this problem was having in the msbuild parameters for the click once publish the assemblyName parameter. If you remove that parameter the build works just fine for the dependent dlls as well.
Since for each project we have qa, beta and production versions and we need to be able to run them side by side on the same computer, we have to have different assembly names for the different builds. If you don't supply the assembly name in the msbuild parameters it takes it from the project file.
The workaround I did for this was created a custom activity that updates the project file with the assemblyName according to the publish type.
If anyone wants I can share the code of the custom activity.
So I change the assembly name in the project file before the publish and it works well!!!